# SciFI/Fantasy novel with a "wizard" who can use magic to interface with technology

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, wizards

There was a novel in which a planet had "wizards" (I can't recall if it was real magic, or ESP).  They sent one of the stronger ones to "spy" on other human planets that didn't have any magic.  He was able to interface with the different machines on these worlds.

I also recall that the planets were in a different dimension or out-of-phase with the rest of the galaxy, which gave them an advantage over the other alien races.  The name of the main character is on the tip of my tongue.  It was in English, and a paperback. It was also a decent sized book, probably around 400-450 pages, if I remember the thickness correctly. I read it around 5 years ago (2010ish). Not sure how old it was at the time, though.

Comment: When did you read this? Was it in English? Paperback or hardback?

Comment: It was in English, and a paperback.  Probably around 400-450 pages, if I remember the thickness correctly.  I read it around 5 years ago.  Not sure how old it was at the time, though.

Comment: Was it stand-alone, or part of a series?  Piers Anthony's Blue Adept/Phaze novels are like this. There is a planet that exists separately in different realities.  One reality was a fantasy world where magic ruled (Proton),  the other was a domed planet where technology ruled (Phaze).  There were certain adepts who could cross over and manipulate things in the technological world to accomplish their ends.  A key feature was that no one could cross over to the other world if their alternate self existed there. Was the main character Stile?

Comment: This sounds like a derivative of "The cyborg and the Sorcerer".  http://a.co/eYGR4s4